# Custom field with InventoryAttribute and PXRestrictor based on ItemClass no longer working in 2018R1

Tags: acumatica

We have a custom field with a lookup/selector for Inventory Item that I had restricted to only a certain item class.  With 2018R1, the ItemClassID field is now an int and I need to compare to the ItemClassCD field.

My PXRestrictor can only access fields from the original DAC.  How best should I rewrite this to accommodate the change to the item class?

```
        #region ParentInventoryID
    [Inventory( IsKey = true, Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible, DisplayName = "Parent Inventory ID")]
    [PXRestrictor(typeof(Where<InventoryItem.itemClassID, Equal<ItemClass.cabledTransceiverFinishedProduct>>), "Parent is not a cabled transceiver finished product.")]
    [PXDefault()]
    [PX.Data.EP.PXFieldDescription] 
    [PXParent(typeof(Select<InventoryItem, Where<InventoryItem.inventoryID, Equal<Current<parentInventoryID>>>>))]
    public Int32? ParentInventoryID { get; set; }
    public abstract class parentInventoryID : IBqlField { }
    #endregion
```

Comment: I think the best solution is to update your string field to use the int value of what you are looking for. The best way would be to use some setup table if the value could change (different itemclass Int value per Acumatica instance). Otherwise you might need to figure out how to join in the INItemClass table into the selector so you can restrict on the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A new table **INItemClass** has been created to store the Inventory Item Class.
InventoryItem.INItemClassID key field points to a **INItemClass** record.

I think that the Inventory attribute doesn't join the INItemClass by default so you would have to add that join in the attribute type parameter.

With the INItemClass join you can restrict on the text field INItemClass.itemClassCD:

```
[Inventory(typeof(Search2<InventoryItem.inventoryID, 
                  InnerJoin<INItemClass, On<INItemClass.itemClassID, Equal<InventoryItem.itemClassID>>>>),
           typeof(InventoryItem.inventoryCD), 
           typeof(InventoryItem.descr), 
           DisplayName = "Parent Inventory ID")]
[PXRestrictor(typeof(Where<INItemClass.itemClassCD, Equal<ItemClass.cabledTransceiverFinishedProduct>>), "Parent is not a cabled transceiver finished product.")]
```

Comment: I was looking for how to do that join; your suggestion for the join results in the Visual Studio warning "'InventoryAttribute.InventoryAttribute(Type)' is obsolete" and a runtime error 

    Exception Details: System.Security.VerificationException: Method PX.Objects.IN.InventoryAttribute.BuildSearch: type argument 'PX.Data.Search2`2[PX.Objects.IN.InventoryItem+inventoryID,PX.Data.InnerJoin`2[PX.Objects.IN.INItemClass,PX.Data.On`2[PX.Objects.IN.INItemClass+itemClassID,PX.Data.Equal`1[PX.Objects.IN.InventoryItem+itemClassID]]]]' violates the constraint of type parameter 'TWhere'.

Comment: It seems to go away if you define all 3 type parameters, I updated my question with the code for the 3 parameters.

Comment: With only 1 type parameter it goes to a different constructor and interpret the parameter differently. I think it is that 1 type constructor that is obsolete and throwing the runtime error, the 3 type one seems to work fine and don't raise an obsolete warning.

Comment: The restrictor appeared to be correctly limiting the displayed data in the selector, but then was raising the error message even though the selected item met the criteria.  

I got around this by adding my criteria to the selector and removing the restrictor, but that seems less than ideal.  Am I misunderstanding the restrictor use?  Do I need to define the criteria in both the selector and the restrictor?  Or is it unhappy because of something else?

Comment: Personally I would have done the same if the restrictor appears to be glitchy. If all you need is to filter the Selector content then putting the filter in the Where clause of the Type parameter is perfectly fine.